# Is it possible to send logs from a ubuntu to Loki?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, azure-devops, grafana, grafana-loki

We are using Azure DevOps to run various pipelines, and I would like to send these logs to a Loki instance. It is possible simply to send all STDOUT from an Ubuntu machine to Loki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you can use the [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to download your pipeline logs. So we have just gone with writing a small kubernetes-cronjob that downloads the pipeline logs based on date filtering and writes them to the STD out of the container. The logs are then picked up by promtail and passed on to loki.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can use the "Promtail" to do this.

See more info about the Promtail at the Loki documentation [here](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/clients/promtail/).

Promtail is released with the Loki releases [here](https://github.com/grafana/loki).

Comment: Is Promtail not a sidecar for Kubernetes, or does it also work just as a vm logging agent?